# Is it correct to say "correct A to B"?

Tags: phrases

In Chinese, when we want to express the idea of "change *A* which is erroneous to *B* which is correct", we usually say "correct *A* to *B*"; very concise, right? But is it the proper way to express that meaning?

If so, please cite a web page containing that expression; if not, present the correct way please and cite a web page too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to use the form "Correct *A* to *B*" for simple sentences.

Some examples:

- *Thus you can have it [correct ‘thier’ to ‘their’](http://readingwritingliving.wordpress.com/2007/05/11/nifty-product-your-own-private-stenographer/) but you can also have it “correct” ‘sth’ to ‘something’, for example.*
- *He forgot to correct ["their" to " his"](http://books.google.com/books?id=U3uaAAAAIAAJ&q=%22correct%20their%20to%22&dq=%22correct%20their%20to%22&hl=en&ei=N-G3TpnJCoyf-Qbi2YmFBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw) in this line.*
- *line 9: [correct 'his' to 'this'](http://books.google.com/books?id=G6iOX47XLsgC&pg=PA154&dq=%22correct%20his%20to%22&hl=en&ei=xeG3Tui_J47n-gbD262FBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22correct%20his%20to%22&f=false).*
- *The reader will [correct "his" to "my"](http://books.google.com/books?id=flk1AQAAIAAJ&q=%22correct%20his%20to%22&dq=%22correct%20his%20to%22&hl=en&ei=xeG3Tui_J47n-gbD262FBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBQ) since Pygmalion was the brother of ...*
- *@Mark sth is an unnecessary abbreviation for something, like sb for somebody. I've [corrected sth.X to X](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/47540/9001)*.

Answer (score -1):

It's not correct to say that. I prefer to use "replace A with B".

e.g. I will replace the broken vase with the new one."

A [link for reference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1441054) as your demand.

Comment: In the fix-a-written-mistake context, it certainly is ok to say "correct A to B."  Granted, in *your* example one cannot correctly replace *replace* with *correct*.

Comment: The problem of "replace A with B" is: it does not implies that A is wrong, unsuitable, unreasonable etc while B is correct, suitable, reasonable .

Comment: Using "correct/to" in the OP's sense is not incorrect, it's simply less idiomatic than "replace/with".